error page not found No object matches the given query
Estoy subiendo a producción una pagina web en Django y me muestra el error de "page not found No object matches the given query". En el servidor localhost la pagina no tiene ningún problema no me muestra ningun error, solo lo hace en producción, yo cambie de base de datos, no se si esa será la causa, en localhost la base de datos por defecto es sqlite3 y en producción la base de datos es mariadb, utilizo ORM para comunicarme con las bases de datos. No se cual puede ser el problema. Me tiene desconcertado.
Ese es el codigo con el que llamo al objeto
